# vb.net - keydown / up issue

Tags: vb.net

I can detect single key downs with this code, however once I push multiple keys vb.net ignores previous key and only focuses on the other key. Can someone help me figure out how to detect multiple keydowns at the same time?

```
Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Or e.KeyCode = Keys.S Or e.KeyCode = Keys.A Or e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        lblDrive.Text = "Driving:     "
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
            lblDrive.Text = lblDrive.Text & "FORWARD  "
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
            lblDrive.Text = lblDrive.Text & "REVERSE  "
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
            lblDrive.Text = lblDrive.Text & "LEFT  "
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
            lblDrive.Text = lblDrive.Text & "RIGHT  "
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you keep a list of keys that are down, and remove them from this list on KeyUp?

The KeyDown event only tells you when a new key is down.  You also won't get KeyDown messages for keys pressed simultaneously... because the keys are never actually pressed simultaneously.

So, upon KeyDown, add the key to your list/array/whatever, and upon KeyUp, remove it from that list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with the exception of modifier keys like Control, Shift and Alt, two keys are never go down at the exact same time.  The operating system will always pick a winner and the down events will be delivered instead in a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this class I wrote:

```
Public Class Keyboard
    Inherits Dictionary(Of Keys, Boolean)

    Public Sub New()
        For Each key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Keys))
            If Not Me.ContainsKey(key) Then Me.Add(key, False)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub KeyDown_Listener(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
        Me(e.KeyCode) = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub KeyUp_Listener(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
        Me(e.KeyCode) = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub LostFocus_Listener(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Keys.Count - 1
            Me(Me.Keys(i)) = False
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Attach(ByVal Control As Control)
        AddHandler Control.KeyDown, AddressOf KeyDown_Listener
        AddHandler Control.KeyUp, AddressOf KeyUp_Listener
        AddHandler Control.LostFocus, AddressOf LostFocus_Listener
    End Sub

    Public Function GetPressedKeys() As List(Of Keys)
        Return (From e As KeyValuePair(Of Keys, Boolean) In Me Where e.Value = True Select e.Key).ToList
    End Function
    Public Function GetUnPressedKeys() As List(Of Keys)
        Return (From e As KeyValuePair(Of Keys, Boolean) In Me Where e.Value = False Select e.Key).ToList
    End Function

    Public Function IsKeyPressed(ByVal Key As Keys) As Boolean
        Return Me(Key)
    End Function

End Class
```

Make it a member of your form class and throw a `Keyboard.Attach(Me)` in there.